# Is a suggested edit appropriate if one does not agree with the code provided in an answer?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I have been spending some time in the suggested edits queue. One of my recent reviews was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13399275) in which the edit suggester suggested changing a boolean parameter from `true` to `false` and indicated in the edit comments that it was a functional change. I naturally rejected this as a disagreement with the answerer that should have been handled with a comment or a separate answer, not an edit, but none of the other reviewers agreed with me.

Did I review incorrectly in this case?

Comment: Great. Now the original answerer [changed it back to be wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36131590/revisions).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you did not review this incorrectly, and your rejection is justified.

*Technically, the adjusted function argument may be correct*. I don't know. Note that the first accepter has various badges for Java, Android, and related stuff - apparently *he* knows, and decided this indeed was a justified adjustment.

But look! It is mentioned in a running sentence that says "remove the following line ..." and that line is a line in the original question!

Editing the "line to remove" into something else cannot ever be correct, useful, or "what the author intended".

(I have rolled it back. Unless this is recurring behavior from either the editor or the accepters, I see no reason for further actions.)

Comment: Note that the answer's author redid the edit. As its owner, they're allowed a bit more leeway, I guess.

Comment: I've always figured that the only valid edits to an answer (ESPECIALLY an already-accepted one) were either from the original author, or grammar/formatting/presentation. Any third-party change to the actual MEANING of the answer should be a comment.